# getting json data from CareerJet Api

Tags: jquery, api

I am a total newbie at JQuery and I am trying to get some data from Careerjet's api.

However, I must tell you that this api is originally provided for Ruby, Java, Php and Perl.

So, I've done some reverse engineering to pick the url structure up and it seemed like that:

```
var url = "http://public.api.careerjet.net/search?locale_code=US_en&pagesize=1&sort=salary&keywords=java&page=124&location=new+york";
```

So, I tried the conventionnal method:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

All I get is:

> "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"

Indeed, the data is never displayed.

I tried to go further and I checked up the HTTP packets in Firebug and I found the expected Json object: `"{"jobs":[{"salary_min":"40000",..."`).

The content-type of the resource is `text/plain`, though... I don't know what this implies.

Comment: AJAX request won't work due to "Cross-Origin Request Policy",  This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS or if API provides callback function.

Comment: A Cross domain request from jquery would not result in this error specific error. It simply triggers the error callback for jquery and tells you that you do not have Cross Origin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript error somewhere in your code, I went to public.api.careerjet.net, Fetched from that url in your example, I received the data with no errors.

Look for syntax errors in your javascript.

This is what I used in jQuery to get the request and see the result.

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://public.api.careerjet.net/search?locale_code=US_en&pagesize=1&sort=salary&keywords=java&page=124&location=new+york"',
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}})
```

Post more of your code if you want me to take a look at your syntax.

Comment: A downvote without reason is just rude. Especially when someone provides code and verifies that what they are trying to accomplish is indeed possible and they went to the trouble to test it for you.